# Dramione fanfic where Draco runs a shop and Hermione begins working for him

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Its a fanfiction on Archive of Our Own and Draco owns a shop in Diagon Alley and I think Blaise is a partner in it. Draco employs Hermione and they fall for each other. I can't remember if the shop is a book shop or a potions shop. I can't remember the name of it and there are so many fanfics to go through.